# Press spacebar when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, google-translate, jsapi, google-translator-toolkit

It is known that spacebar must be pressed to translate while using google transliteration.

But requirement is to translate already stored value in input fetched from database, not a live user typed value.

I doubt we can translate input value automatically with google [jspi](http://www.google.com/jsapi).

It is not possible to translate without hitting spacebar so I am trying to press spacebar to each class when a specific button is clicked, so it would be translated.

For example, here is button, if this button is clicked then press spacebar to each class and translate automatically.

I tried with appending space after the value, but without spacebar event nothing change

```
$('#translate').click(function(){
    $('.npl').each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val()+'');
    })
})
$('.npl').nepalize();
```

```js
$.fn.nepalize = function(){
  var that = this[0];
  google.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "transliteration"
  });
  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
      sourceLanguage: 'en', // or google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
      destinationLanguage: ['ne'], // or [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
      shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
      transliterationEnabled: true
    };
    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given Class.
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('npl');
    control.makeTransliteratable(elements);  
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
}

$('#translate').click(function(){
  $('.npl').each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val()+'');
  })
})
$('.npl').nepalize();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id='translate'>Translate</button>
  <input class="npl" value='Hello'>
  <input class="npl" value='How are you' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it should be comment section, but I have to explain and inserting example here. In Google transliterate official website, it is mentioned how `javascript` string can be translated.

**I think solution is in following code**

https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started

```
//Load the Language API.
google.load("language", "1");

//Call google.language.transliterate() 
google.language.transliterate(["Namaste"], "en", "hi", function(result) {
  if (!result.error) {
    var container = document.getElementById("transliteration");
    if (result.transliterations && result.transliterations.length > 0 &&
        result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords.length > 0) {
      container.innerHTML = result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords[0];
    }
  }
});
```

If javascript string can be converted, It would be the best way as we can store string from database.

**I tried with this, but result is blank**

```js
    google.load("language", "1");

    function initialize() {
      google.language.transliterate(["Namaste"], "en", "ne", function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("transliteration");
          if (result.transliterations && result.transliterations.length > 0 &&
            result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords.length > 0) {
            container.innerHTML = result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords[0];
          }
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google AJAX Language API - Basic Transliteration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="transliteration"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```